# How to loop backwards in python?

Tags: python, iteration, range

I'm talking about doing something like:

```
for(i=n; i>=1; --i) {
   //do something with i
}
```

I can think of some ways to do so in python (creating a list of `range(1,n+1)` and reverse it, using `while` and `--i`, ...) but I wondered if there's a more elegant way to do it. Is there?

EDIT:
Some suggested I use xrange() instead of range() since range returns a list while xrange returns an iterator. But in Python 3 (which I happen to use) range() returns an iterator and xrange doesn't exist.

Comment: a little too late to answer but, I didn't see the easiest solution here so here it is..........................................................`for i in range(n)[::-1]` this will give you `i` in reverse order. Peace out.

Comment: @ParthikB wouldn't the reverse in the end create extra space? looks like you are creating a new reversed array - i may be wrong?

Answer (score 457, accepted):

`range()` and `xrange()` take a third parameter that specifies a step. So you can do the following.

```
range(10, 0, -1)
```

Which gives

```
[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

But for iteration, you should really be using `xrange` instead. So,

```
xrange(10, 0, -1)
```

> Note for Python 3 users: There are no separate `range` and `xrange` functions in Python 3, there is just `range`, which follows the design of Python 2's `xrange`.

Comment: Since this question is about iteration please use xrange instead of range (doesn't matter much for small ranges but starts mattering for large ones).

Comment: @mzz -- only in Python 2.x

Comment: I used `range` simply because the OP did. `xrange` vs `range` only matters for _really_ large ranges, like hundreds of megabytes. Also, in Python 3.x, this distinction is gone.

Comment: @Chinmay, why not use your answer as a way of showing best practices to the OP? No reason *not* to suggest using `xrange`.

Comment: What is xrange? Is it the same as range but faster? If so then why is it faster?

Comment: `xrange` produces a _generator_ instead of a `list`. What this means is that instead of taking up all the memory at the start, the value required is produced at the time when it's required. For more details, see http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#generators

Comment: Turns out xrange doesn't exist in python 3...

Comment: No, it doesn't. Your question didn't specify which version of python you were using, and the default assumption tends to be python 2.x

Comment: i think you should use range(10, -1, -1) instead of range(10, 0, -1).
because range(10, 0, -1) will stop at the index 0, as a result, the index 0 value will not print.

Comment: To Clarify: In Python 3 the Python 2 xrange() function has been renamed as just range() and there is no function which has the same behaviour as the Python 2 range() function. See: [What’s New In Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists)

Comment: Actually you should use range(n-1, -1, -1), this will provide the values between zero and n-1. Both this answer and some of the comments have off-by-one issues.

Comment: Yeah in this example you would use (9,-1,-1)

Comment: @ChrisFlesher  you can simply use `range(n)[::-1]` which is translated to `range(n-1, -1, -1)` (tested in python 3.7)

Answer (score 261):

```
for x in reversed(whatever):
    do_something()
```

This works on basically everything that has a defined order, including `xrange` objects and lists.

Comment: @Odomontois, no, it doesn't. It returns an iterator.

Comment: Yes. Sorry. It returns result of obj.__reversed__ method. So by default generator objects haven't this like many others iterables. And even reversed(reversed([1,2,3])) raises TypeError. So you HAVE to create a list before send some iterable to reversed in many situations like reversed([expr(i) for i in iterable if cond(i)]) - without brackets it falls.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer imo

Comment: The reason this should be accepted is that `reversed(range(3))` produces 2, 1, 0 which is exactly the reverse of `range(3)` while you would have to otherwise do something like `range(3-1, 0-1, -1)` to get the same. It's also more readable than `range(3)[::-1]`.

Comment: This is the best answer, as other comments state, and for instance, try: `for i, val in enumerate(reversed(range(6))): print(i, val)`

Comment: Doesn't this require the entire range to be allocated in memory at the outset of the iteration?

Answer (score 22):

All of these three solutions give the same results if the input is a string:

1.

```
def reverse(text):
    result = ""
    for i in range(len(text),0,-1):
        result += text[i-1]
    return (result)
```

2.

```
text[::-1]
```

3.

```
"".join(reversed(text))
```

Comment: which is the recommended method depending on situation?

Comment: does #1 suggestion still work on latest python version ? Tried it and its `list index out of range`

Answer (score 12):

```
def reverse(text):
    reversed = ''
    for i in range(len(text)-1, -1, -1):
        reversed += text[i]
    return reversed

print("reverse({}): {}".format("abcd", reverse("abcd")))
```

Comment: This is the best answer.  

Iterating through the values like with a for loop is not what people want every time.

Iterating by index is far more flexible.

Comment: This is by no means the best answer. To iterate in reverse with an index (if that's what you want, and the criteria you are using to say it's better) then use `range` with `reversed` as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3476753); it's far simpler.

Answer (score 2):

To reverse a string without using `reversed` or `[::-1]`, try something like:

```
def reverse(text):
    # Container for reversed string
    txet=""

    # store the length of the string to be reversed
    # account for indexes starting at 0
    length = len(text)-1

    # loop through the string in reverse and append each character
    # deprecate the length index
    while length>=0:
        txet += "%s"%text[length]
        length-=1
    return txet
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this way? This is rather simple:
def reverse(text):
    new_text = ""
    for char in text:
        new_text = char + new_text
    return new_text