# How to implement pre and post increment in Python lists?

Tags: java, python, post-increment, pre-increment

In Python how can we increment or decrement an index within the square braces of a list?

For instance, in Java the following code

```
array[i] = value
i--
```

can be written as

```
array[i--]
```

In **Python**, how can we implement it?
`list[i--]` is not working

I am currently using

```
list[i] = value 
i -= 1
```

Please suggest a concise way of implementing this step.

Comment: There's no reasonable way to do this, although of course there's always hacks like defining your own integer class with a 'return the current value and then decrement' method.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Python does not have a -- or ++ command. For reasons why,  see [Why are there no ++ and --​ operators in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654830/why-are-there-no-and-operators-in-python)

Your method is idiomatic Python and works fine - I see no reason to change it.

Answer (score 4):

If what you need is to iterate backwards over a list, this may help you:

```
>>> a = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
>>> for i in reversed(a):
...     print i
... 
baz
bar
foo
```

Or:

```
for item in my_list[::-1]:
    print item
```

The first way is how "it should be" in Python.

For more examples:

- [Traverse a list in reverse order in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529424/traverse-a-list-in-reverse-order-in-python)
- [How to loop backwards in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476732/how-to-loop-backwards-in-python)