# Python decrementing loop

Tags: python, loops, decrement

i have a loop but its incrementing. what is the syntax for decrementing the loop?

```
for item2 in textPad.get(itemindex,END):
    tagnames = textPad.tag_names(str(curline)+"."+str(curchar))
    if not "phpsingqoute" in tagnames and not "phpdoubqoute" in tagnames and not "phpcomment" in tagnames:
        if item2 == theopenandclose[1]:
            opencount -= 1
            if opencount == 0:
                textPad.tag_add(tagname,str(curline)+"."+str(curchar))
                textPad.tag_config(tagname,foreground="white",background="#000")
                break
        if item2 == theopenandclose[0]:
            opencount += 1
    if re.match(r'\n',item2):
        curline += 1
        curchar = -1
    curchar += 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `textPad.get` returns a list, you can use `reversed`

```
for item2 in reversed(textPad.get(itemindex,END)):
```

This will also work for some other iterable types, but not all. [See the documentation.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed) If you get a `TypeError`, try converting the result of textPad.get to a list first.:

```
for item2 in reversed(list(textPad.get(itemindex,END))):
```

Answer (score 0):

can not add a comment
the answer is `reversed(...)`

[Post before in this forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476732/how-to-loop-backwards-in-python)