# Python: not printing int, only string value

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
print ('Hello')

for i in range(2,11,-2):
    print(i)
```

Whats wrong with this code? I'm trying to print out :

```
Hello
10
8
6
4
2
```

but it only prints out hello. I ctrl+enter twice after print hello

Comment: [`range(10, 1, -2)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to loop backwards in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476732/how-to-loop-backwards-in-python)

Comment: You are trying to loop from 2 to 11 _in steps of -2_ which actually means backwards and in steps of 2. As it is not possible, it prints nothing. The initial end final values must be corrected

Comment: Consider `test = [1,2,3]`. If I slice `test[100:]` I get an empty list, not an error, even though the start value overflowed the range. Its the same thing for, say, `range(100,3)` - since you've already gone over the top in the first step, it just stops iteration. Finally to `range(2, 11, -2)`. Its going backwards, 11 is already "behind" what you can get going backwards, so it stops.

Comment: @StephenRauch - I didn't see the duplicate there. It shows negative steps to go backwards but doesn't explain why this range test stops without producing anything.

Answer (score 3):

If you specify a negative step in `range` you also have to make start bigger than stop:

```
for i in range(10,0,-2):
    print(i)
```

Another way to do what you want, would be to use `reversed`:

```
for i in reversed(range(2,11,2)):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

The range() function will include the first value and exclude the second.

```
a = " ".join(str(i) for i in range(10, 0, -2))
print (a)
```

Comment: But what makes this work is the reversal of the start and stop conditions, not the join, or the inclusion / exclusion rules.

Answer (score 2):

Read what [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#func-range) does. First argument is a starting number, you can't start from smaller if you want to print from bigger to smaller.

You can do `range(2, 11, 2)` for increasingly list or `range(10, 1, -2)` for decreasingly.

There's also reverse `range(2, 11, 2)[::-1]` option, but its better to just use it as planned.

Answer (score 1):

Since your range starts at 2, and ends at 11, this code won't work since you are stepping down by -2. You will have to START at 10 and then step down negatively instead of stepping down from 2. Below I have an example that gets you the output that you are seeking:

```
print('Hello')

for i in range(10, 1, -2):
     print(i)
```

And here is your output:

```
Hello
10
8
6
4
2
```