# How do I move list elements to another list if a condition is met?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of values and I want to move certain (or all) values to another list if they exist in a reference list.

```
x = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8] # list of values
ref = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8] # reference list
result = [x.pop(i) for i, v in enumerate(x) if v in ref]
```

But because of popping the current index, it ends up giving every other value instead. Is there a nice straightforward way to do this?

What I want at the end of this example is `x=[]` and `result=[2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`, but `ref` doesn't need to contain all elements of `x`, this was just for an example. In another case it might be:

```
x = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8] # list of values
ref = [2,6,7] # reference list
```

So then I want `x = [3,4,5,8]` and `result = [2,6,7]`

Comment: Similar problem: [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](/q/1207406/4518341)

Comment: @wjandrea It is similar but I wanted in one shot to take from list `x` and move it into `result` if the condition is met. I need both to be updated in this process, but these solutions seem to just be creating a new list or updating the current one which is not what I am trying to accomplish. Maybe I am asking for the impossible, but since pop is so nice with a single element I figured there might be some way to just pop & append in a loop

Comment: Why? The alternative seems to (1) append matching elements to a new list, and then (2) loop back again and remove the matching elements from x. This means there is a point in time where the same element exists in both lists which is also quite ugly

Comment: [How to split a list based on a condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/949098/12671057)

Comment: *"there is a point in time where the same element exists in both lists"* - And if you pop and append individually, there is a point in time where the element exists in **neither** iist. Is that really less "ugly"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it the old-fashioned way, with a while loop and a pointer into `x`:

```
x = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
ref = [2, 6, 7]

result = []
i = 0
while i < len(x):
    if x[i] in ref:
        result.append(x.pop(i))
    else:
        i += 1

print(x)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, we should avoid modifying objects while iterating over them.

For this problem, we could generate `result` and filter `x` in two steps using comprehensions (avoiding appending to lists) as in the following example.

```
result, x = [v for v in x if v in ref], [v for v in x if v not in ref]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply [iterate from the end to the start](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3476768/11112152) to avoid pop() changing the list size while iterating. Just call reverse() on your new list after running your loop if the order of the list matters.